# Help with loop/counter script

Tags: bash, script

I'm trying to create a simple loop/counter script to display information about installed printers.  Main the Name, PPD, PPD Version, and URI.  I have two problems...  1 - the name is not coming up; 2 - the second printer PPD is incorrect.

Here what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | /usr/bin/awk -F ":" '/Name/{$1="";print $0}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/\ /-,--/g'))
ppd=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | /usr/bin/awk -F ":" '/PPD/{$1="";print $0}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/\ /-,--/g'))
ppdversion=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | /usr/bin/awk -F ":" '/PPD File Version/{$1="";print $0}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/\ /-,--/g'))
uri=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | /usr/bin/awk '/URI/{print $NF}'))
total="${#ppdversion[@]}"
/bin/echo -n "<result>"
for ((counter=0; counter < "$total"; counter++))
{
    echo "name: ${name[$counter]}" | /usr/bin/sed 's/-,--/\ /g;s/\ \ //g'
    echo "PPD: ${ppd[$counter]}" | /usr/bin/sed 's/-,--/\ /g;s/\ \ //g'
    echo "PPD Version: ${ppdversion[$counter]}" | /usr/bin/sed 's/-,--/\ /g;s/\ \ //g'
    echo "URI: ${uri[$counter]}"
    echo
}
echo "</result>"
```

The output:

```
<result>
name: 
PPD: Canon MX410 series
PPD Version: 16.10.0.0
URI: lpd://printer.local


name: 
PPD: 16.10.0.0
PPD Version: 16.10.0.0
URI: dnssd://Canon%20MX410%20series%20_1B181C000000._printer._tcp.local./auto

</result>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The script is searching for "Name" - but no field entitled "Name" exists, so nothing is found. There is an alternate command `lpstat` that may be easier to parse the name from, and returns the same ordering:

   ```
   /usr/bin/lpstat -p | awk '{print $2}'
   ```
2. Since `PPD` is also in `PPD Version`, this causes a conflict. Search instead for `PPD:`, like the following:

   ```
   ppd=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType \
              | /usr/bin/awk -F ":" '/PPD:/{$1="";print $0}' \
              | /usr/bin/sed 's/\ /-,--/g'))
   ```

Here's a complete script - it appears to do what you want:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 name=($(/usr/bin/lpstat -p | awk '{print $2}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/\ /-,--/g'))
 ppd=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | /usr/bin/awk -F ":" '/PPD:/{$1="";print $0}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/\ /-,--/g'))
 ppdversion=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | /usr/bin/awk -F ":" '/PPD File Version/{$1="";print $0}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/\ /-,--/g'))
 uri=($(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPrintersDataType | /usr/bin/awk '/URI/{print $NF}'))
 total="${#ppdversion[@]}"
 /bin/echo "<result>"
 for ((counter=0; counter < "$total"; counter++))
 {
     echo "name: ${name[$counter]}" | /usr/bin/sed 's/-,--/\ /g;s/\ \ //g'
     echo "PPD: ${ppd[$counter]}" | /usr/bin/sed 's/-,--/\ /g;s/\ \ //g'
     echo "PPD Version: ${ppdversion[$counter]}" | /usr/bin/sed 's/-,--/\ /g;s/\ \ //g'
     echo "URI: ${uri[$counter]}"
     echo
 }
 echo "</result>"
```

The output (for my installed printers):

```
<result>
name: Brother_MFC_9325CW
PPD: Brother MFC-9325CW CUPS
PPD Version: 4.5.2
URI: usb://Brother/MFC-9325CW?serial=000L2J998184

name: Canon_MX410
PPD: Canon MX410 series
PPD Version: 16.10.0.0
URI: dnssd://Canon%20MX410._printer._tcp.local./auto

</result>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea what the printer name field is?

Comment: @WebsterMaster Working on it... :)

Comment: This places a bet on `lpstat` and `system_profiler` using the same sort order for printers :-)

Comment: The name actually *is* in the output, but difficult to parse. May be easier to run `system_profiler -xml` and use one of the tools in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash#894317 to parse the XML result.